# Laravel named route with {parametr}

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, routes

```
Route::match(['patch','put'],'/edit/{id}', 'TestController@update')->name('update');
```

using `route()` helper in form action I expected to see

```
https://example.com/edit/1
```

And what I get using `{{ route('update', $article->id) }}` is `https://example.com/edit?1`

Any ideas how to resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try passing the `id` in as an array:

```
route('update', ['id' => $article->id])
```

and make sure the form's method attribute is `post` as well as setting the correct `_method` value within the form:

```
<form action="{{ route('upate', ['id' => $article->id]) }}" method="post">
    {{ method_field('patch') }}
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for that, both answers are correct. Maybe I just used that on incorrect form with GET method.I have a lot of forms... My bad.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your example and it seems to work as expected. Going by the `?` in the URL, my guess would be that it is a `GET` instead of `POST` in the form? Could you confirm that?

Comment: Ye, u r right, probably I made some simple mistake and didn't notice it. But it really works as expected...